# TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/register/ accounts/register.html

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-templates

why i still getting this error even though i already create register.html? i already read about this error and i already try to put in settings.py : `TEMPLATES_DIRS [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/profiles/accounts/templates')]` and still nothing have changed .

i try to create my own customize registration form . can anyone help me please ? im new in django and python .

i dont know what went wrong because i already create the template by following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5x97gGspzjY

settings.py :

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ... default django apps ...
    'profiles',
    'contact',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'checkout',
    'custom_user'
]

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/profiles/accounts/templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

project structure :

```
C:.
├───checkout
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───contact
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───custom_user
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───profiles
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───accounts
│   └───__pycache__
├───register
│   ├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
├───sqlite
└───tryFOUR
    └───__pycache_
```

register/views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

#Create your views here
def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect ('home.html')
        else:
            return render(request, '/profiles/accounts/register.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        return render(request, '/profiles/accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

profiles/views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from custom_user.forms import CustomUserCreationForm

#Create your views here
def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, "login.html", c)

def about(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'about.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

@login_required
def userProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {'user': user}
    template = 'profile.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get['username', '']
    password = request.POST.get['password', '']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HTTpResponseRedirect('account/login')
    else:
        return HTTpResponseRedirect('account/login')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect ('/accounts/register_success')

    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register', args)


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render(request, 'logout.html')
```

Comment: Please show the whole TEMPLATES setting.

Comment: done @DanielRoseman

Comment: it has error :   ]
    ^  syntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing @xyres

Comment: @nuradilla I removed the extra code which was not relevant to the error from this question. You were not supposed to copy it from here and paste it to your settings file.

Comment: can you explain your statement ? i thought if i removed all the extra code as you did, it will fix the error. im soo sorry for asking like this @xyres im soo confused right now

Comment: @nuradilla I removed that code because it had nothing to do with the problem you had. By removing it, the question has become shorter and easier for others to read and follow. Read this: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info.

Comment: Okay i get it . Im sooo sorry @xyres

Comment: Can you show here your project directory structure? that will helpful for us to understand where is your template location.

Comment: done @NeErAjKuMaR . the register.html is in profiles/templates/accounts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you out,

> https://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/

and you should define TEMPLATES_DIR properly

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [
            # Absolute path of your TEMPLATE_DIR
        ],
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
Change your Templates settings to this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

APP_DIRS=True means Django will look for templates in each app directory.
Since you have all of your templates in your app directories you may not need to specify **'DIRS'** option in the template directory. That option is used to specify any additional folder you want to kame Django look for templates.

Now you need to change your views like this:

register/views.py:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

 #Create your views here
 def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect ('home.html')
        else:
           return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Since **profile** is an app you don't need to specify that in your template path.

profiles/views.py:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
 from custom_user.forms import CustomUserCreationForm

 #Create your views here
 def home(request):
     return render(request, "home.html")

 def login(request):
     c = {}
     c.update(csrf(request))
     return render(request, "login.html", c)

 def about(request):
     context = locals()
     template = 'about.html'
     return render(request,template,context)

@login_required
def userProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {'user': user}
    template = 'profile.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get['username', '']
    password = request.POST.get['password', '']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HTTpResponseRedirect('account/login')
    else:
        return HTTpResponseRedirect('account/login')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect ('/accounts/register_success')

    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', args)


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render(request, 'logout.html')
```

**Make sure all the templates specified in the above views are in the templates folder of any of the apps.** Because Django first looks in the current app directory and then looks on other apps directories.

For example, in case of `accounts/register.html`, you should either

Make a directory **accounts** inside the templates folder inside your **register** app and put **register.html** inside the accounts folder

**OR**

Make sure you put your register.html inside `profile/templates/accounts/`

> **AND FINALLY**

These are very basics of a Django application. You should really pay attention on the tutorial you are following. I think you missed some and thats what put you into this problem. That happens. So before you ask please put some effort finding the solution on the internet. The best option is to start from the
[Django Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/)

Comment: It still the same :( nothing changed . What did i do wrong :(((( i try to fix the error for 1 hour already :"(((

Comment: Can you include the project structure and your views in the question?